# MailMessage Attachment on IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, mailmessage

I am currently having an issue where I am creating a MailMessage with attachments. This works perfectly well on a local server, however once it is moved to a remote server, the application is unable to find the files that were attached. The code I am using is:

```
foreach (string s in e.attachments)
{
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(s));
}
```

Where e.attachments is simply a `List<string>` of paths to files on the client's computer.

The error message I am receiving is:

[image: Error message]

I'm assuming this is happening because the application is looking at the C: drive of the server it is running on. How would I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Web servers can't magically access the file systems of client PC's. You could probably make it happen in a corporate intranet environment but it'd be a poor design and prone to all sorts of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to upload the attachment to the server.
As you say, the file you are trying to attach is on your local storage and not on your webserver.

[This](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/) post should help you uploading your attachments:

Cheers, Martin